# Print json block from a json array on new line joined by '#'

Tags: bash, jq

I have a json array that looks as below -

```
[
  {
    "Code": "some code",
    "Name": "some name",
    "Country": "some country",
    "Cost": "some cost",
    "Type": "Some type"
  },{
    "Code": "some code",
    "Name": "some name",
    "Country": "some country",
    "Cost": "some cost",
    "Type": "Some type"
  },{
    "Code": "some code",
    "Name": "some name",
    "Country": "some country",
    "Cost": "some cost",
    "Type": "Some type"
  }
]
```

I am trying print each json block on a new line with fields separated by `'#'`

**Expected output**

```
some code#some name#some country#some cost#some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#some type
```

I've tried the code below which separates the content with `'#'`. However, it merges all blocks into a single line like this - `some code#some name#some country#some cost#some type#some code#some name#some country#some cost#some type#some code#some name#some country#some cost#some type`

```
 cat contents.json | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | awk  -F ': *' 'BEGIN { RS=",\n\"|\n}," } { gsub(/[\n\]\[\}]/,"",$2); if ($2) { printf("%s#", $2); } }'
```

Please could someone guide me to et this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jq, the `join` builtin, when applied to an object, will pull out the field values and concatenate them using a separator string. The `-r` option ensures that raw text is being output (rather than JSON).

```sh
jq -r '.[] | join("#")' contents.json
```

```
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/w9W3KVgHu6)

---

Update: If in the input objects the keys cannot be guaranteed to always be in the same order, just specify their order explicitly using an array.

```sh
jq -r '.[] | [.Code,.Name,.Country,.Cost,.Type] | join("#")' contents.json
```

```
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0Nyy-3Hlr0)

Comment: Note that this assumes the keys are in the same order in each object, something one shouldn't rely on.

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) over `jq` for dealing with JSON, but in this case the JSON is compatible and `mlr` powerful features could become handy for further processing of the input:

```sh
mlr --ijson --ocsv --ofs '#' unsparsify file.json
```

```
Code#Name#Country#Cost#Type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
some code#some name#some country#some cost#Some type
```

**notes:**

- You can avoid displaying the header with the `-N` option
- Unordered or missing keys in the JSON objects won't break the output